# SUNFLOW: Paint only contour edges of 3D mesh

Tags: java, 3d, paint, mesh

This is literal copy of WireframeShader from really old and long time abandoned java app called Sunflow:

```
package org.sunflow.core.shader;

import org.sunflow.SunflowAPI;
import org.sunflow.core.ParameterList;
import org.sunflow.core.Shader;
import org.sunflow.core.ShadingState;
import org.sunflow.image.Color;
import org.sunflow.math.Matrix4;
import org.sunflow.math.Point3;

public class WireframeShader implements Shader {

    private Color lineColor;
    private Color fillColor;
    private float width;
    private float cosWidth;

    public WireframeShader() {
        lineColor = Color.BLACK;
        fillColor = Color.WHITE;
        // pick a very small angle - should be roughly the half the angular width of a pixel
        width = (float) (Math.PI * 0.5 / 4096);
        cosWidth = (float) Math.cos(width);
    }

    public boolean update(ParameterList pl, SunflowAPI api) {
        lineColor = pl.getColor("line", lineColor);
        fillColor = pl.getColor("fill", fillColor);
        width = pl.getFloat("width", width);
        cosWidth = (float) Math.cos(width);
        return true;
    }

    public Color getMaterialColor() {
        return lineColor;
    }

    public Color getFillColor(ShadingState state) {
        return fillColor;
    }

    public Color getLineColor(ShadingState state) {
        return lineColor;
    }

    public Color getRadiance(ShadingState state) {
        Point3[] p = new Point3[3];
        if (!state.getTrianglePoints(p)) {
            return getFillColor(state);
        }
        // transform points into camera space
        Point3 center = state.getPoint();
        Matrix4 w2c = state.getWorldToCamera();
        center = w2c.transformP(center);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            p[i] = w2c.transformP(state.getInstance().transformObjectToWorld(p[i]));
        }
        float cn = 1.0f / (float) Math.sqrt(center.x * center.x + center.y * center.y + center.z * center.z);
        for (int i = 0, i2 = 2; i < 3; i2 = i, i++) {
            // compute orthogonal projection of the shading point onto each triangle edge as in:
            // http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html
            float t = (center.x - p[i].x) * (p[i2].x - p[i].x);
            t += (center.y - p[i].y) * (p[i2].y - p[i].y);
            t += (center.z - p[i].z) * (p[i2].z - p[i].z);
            t /= p[i].distanceToSquared(p[i2]);
            float projx = (1 - t) * p[i].x + t * p[i2].x;
            float projy = (1 - t) * p[i].y + t * p[i2].y;
            float projz = (1 - t) * p[i].z + t * p[i2].z;
            float n = 1.0f / (float) Math.sqrt(projx * projx + projy * projy + projz * projz);
            // check angular width
            float dot = projx * center.x + projy * center.y + projz * center.z;
            if (dot * n * cn >= cosWidth) {
                return getLineColor(state);
            }
        }
        return getFillColor(state);
    }

    public void scatterPhoton(ShadingState state, Color power) {
    }

    @Override
    public float getReflectionValue() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

It would render any 3D mesh so that every edge of mesh triangle would be painted thus creating a wireframe-like visual (see pic below)

[image]

My question is: does anybody know how to change/update the code (specifically getRadiance() method) so it would only paint contour edges of mesh so it would look like in the pic below?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is harder than you think, because it cannot be done by using information from just a single triangle. You need to check all edges in the mesh and for each edge take the two faces which contain it. You draw the edge if and only if the normals of these two faces are not the same (differ enough).